# How can I select multiple items at once in Telerik RadEditor on Chrome?

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, telerik, internet-explorer-11, radeditor

I am working on an application based on ASP.NET, running in IE11 and Chrome.

One part of the application makes use of (Telerik) RadEditor to create a layout of several items.

I can select (selection border shows up on all selected elements) multiple elements in the page (in the (Telerik) RadEditor content space) by holding control+clicking in IE11, but I cannot do the same in Chrome. In Chrome it just selects the last thing clicked.

Is there a way to multi-select like this in Chrome, or a reason it works in IE11 but not in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

The IE browser's execCommand method offers a **MultipleSelection** option which allows for the selection of more than one site selectable element at a time when the user holds down the SHIFT or CTRL keys. You can find more info at [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/hh801232(v%3dvs.85)#multipleselection](http://MultipleSelection%20Allows%20for%20the%20selection%20of%20more%20than%20one%20site%20selectable%20element%20at%20a%20time%20when%20the%20user%20holds%20down%20the%20SHIFT%20or%20CTRL%20keys.)

To fire this method via the RadEditor API do:

```
editor.get_document().execCommand('MultipleSelection', true, true);
```

To get reference on the client object of RadEditor check this resource https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/editor/client-side-programming/getting-a-reference-to-radeditor